# Filling two colors when one curve is above or below the other

Tags: plotting, filling

Let's plot two functions $2e^{-\pi x^2}$ and $e^{-x}$ and fill the area between two curves with two colors depending on the sign of their difference. However, the following code does not work:

```
Plot[{2 E^(-Pi x^2), E^(-x)}, {x, 0, 5},PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, Red}}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

However, if start the plot with $-0.01$, it works!

```
Plot[{2 E^(-Pi x^2), E^(-x)}, {x, -.01, 5},PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, Red}}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Why is it so weird?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `MaxRecursion->r` and let `r<4`. Maybe a bug.

```
r=2;
Plot[{2  E^(-Pi  x^2), E^(-x)}, {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
   Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, Red}}}, PlotRange -> All, 
   MaxRecursion -> r]
```

[image]

Comment: Even manually specifying `PlotPoints` seems to work, for example `PlotPoints -> 2` ...

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, plotting over the `Interval` {0,5} works as well as this can be changed.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f1 = 2 E^(-Pi x^2);
f2 = E^(-x);
c1 = Opacity[0.2, ColorData[97][1]];
c2 = Opacity[0.2, ColorData[97][2]];

Plot[{f1, f2}, x ∈ Interval[{0, 5}]
 , PlotRange -> All
 , Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {c2, c1}}}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {f1, f2}], {0.8, 0.6}]
 ]
```

**Original:**

On v12.2.0 running on Win7-x64, there seems to be no issue.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f1 = 2 E^(-Pi x^2);
f2 = E^(-x);
c1 = Opacity[0.2, ColorData[97][1]];
c2 = Opacity[0.2, ColorData[97][2]];

Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, -1, 3}
 , Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {c2, c1}}}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {f1, f2}], {0.8, 0.6}]
 ]
```

---

[image]

---

```
Plot[{f1, f2}, {x, 0, 3}
 , Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {c2, c1}}}
 , PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Automatic, {f1, f2}], {0.8, 0.6}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work for particular ranges of $x$. Namely, please try with `{x, 0, 5}`.

Comment: I see; I will delete the answer since the choice of domain affects the filling. Thanks @Domen

Comment: Domen Can you please check if the workaround works for other versions.

Comment: The workaround with `Interval` works for [v13.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BuiQ.png) and [v14.0 (Cloud)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewWXR.png).